# number of zeros in a disk of a holomorphic function

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function defined in a beighborhood of $\overline{D(0,R)}$ which has no zeros on $\partial D(0,R)$. Let $N$ be the number of zeros of $f$ inside $D(0,R)$. Prove that
\begin{equation}
\max _{|z|=R}\text{Re}\left(z\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\right)\geq N.
\end{equation}

How to prove?

My idea: I write $f(z)=(z-z_1)\cdots (z-z_N)g(z)$ and calculated out that
\begin{equation}
\int_{|z|=R}\left(z\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\right)dz=2\pi i\sum_{k=1}^Nz_k.
\end{equation}
I also know by Argument Principle,
 \begin{equation}
2\pi iN=\int_{|z|=R}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz.
\end{equation}
But I do not know how to continue...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Observe that
$$N = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=R}\frac{f^\prime(z)}{f(z)}dz = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{f^\prime(Re^{i\theta})}{f(Re^{i\theta})}iRe^{i\theta}d\theta = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{f^\prime(Re^{i\theta})}{f(Re^{i\theta})}Re^{i\theta}d\theta,$$
implying that
$$N = \mathrm{Re}(N) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm{Re}\left(\frac{f^\prime(Re^{i\theta})}{f(Re^{i\theta})}Re^{i\theta}\right)d\theta.$$
If we were to assume that for all $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$ it holds that $\mathrm{Re}\left(\frac{f^\prime(Re^{i\theta})}{f(Re^{i\theta})}Re^{i\theta}\right)<N$, we would therefore derive a contradiction.